# How to convert URL into Unmanaged<CFURL> using Swift?

Tags: swift

In Swift I am trying to create an `AUSamplerBankPresetData` object which requires an `Unmanaged<CFURL>` object.

How do I convert a URL object into `Unmanaged<CFURL>` in swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to convert your `URL` into a `CFURL`. This can be done with an unconditional cast so:

```swift
let cfurl = url as CFURL
```

Then, to create an unmanaged reference to that `CFURL` you'll need to use one of the functions outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged) to create an `Unmanaged` object. Make sure you choose the right one for your application. The example below will increment the reference count, so you will need to make sure that it is decremented later.

```swift
var um = Unmanaged<CFURL>.passRetained(cfurl)
```

Comment: Note that `passRetained()` increases the refcount, so this must be balanced eventually to avoid a memory leak.